# How do I make this search form appear correctly on IE6 - IE8?

Tags: html, css, forms, internet-explorer, frontend

I'm working on an app and part of the project requirements is that the entire site be compatible with IE6 - IE8. So far, the rest of the website looks good on older browsers except for this search form I created.

This is what it looks like on modern browsers, and is what it's supposed to look like in general: [image: This is what it looks like on modern browsers],

...but this is what it looks like on IE6: [image: this is what it looks like on IE6].

Does anyone have some experience with trying to make table-less layouts work on older browsers, or has run into a similar issue in the past? Basically I have containers holding each label / input, and need them to display next to each other in three's per row, with the label and input next to each other ass seen on the first image.

Below is the code regarding these elements.

**EDIT: I added a few more things to both the html and css for easier deployment on your own computers.**

Thanks for any help you can provide!

**HTML**

```
<div class="mid">
<h2>Search and filter by:</h2>
<!-- 1st Row Starts -->
<form action="" method="post" id="main-search-form"> <!-- containing form for search -->
<div id="search-container" align="center">
<div class="search" align="center">
      <form>
        <label>Keywords</label>
        <input type="text" name="keywords" value="" id="keywords" placeholder="enter search terms here...">
     </form>
</div>
<div class="search" align="center">    
    <label>Category</label>
    <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
        <option value="">Category 1</option>
        <option value="">Category 2</option>
        <option value="">Category 3</option>
        <option value="">Category 4</option>
        <option value="">Category 5</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="search" align="center">
    <label>Service</label>
    <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Service</option>
        <option value="food">Food and Nutrition Support</option>
        <option value="shelter">Shelter and Care</option>
        <option value="protection">Protection</option>
        <option value="healthcare">Healthcare</option>
        <option value="pyschosocial">Psychosocial Support Services</option>
        <option value="education">Formal and informal education</option>
        <option value="legal">Legal Services</option>
        <option value="other">Other Services</option>
    </select>
</div>       
</div> <!-- //.search-container -->
<!-- // 1st Row  -->

<!-- 2nd Row Starts -->
<div id="search-container" align="center">
<div class="search" align="center">
    <label>Age</label>
    <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Age</option>
        <option value="">Age 1-3</option>
        <option value="">Age 4-10</option>
        <option value="">Age 11-14</option>
        <option value="">Age 15-18</option>
    </select>
</div> 
<div class="search" align="center">
    <label>Gender</label>
    <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Gender</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="search" align="center">
    <label>Region</label>
    <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Region</option>
        <option value="">Category 1</option>
        <option value="">Category 2</option>
        <option value="">Category 3</option>
        <option value="">Category 4</option>
        <option value="">Category 5</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div><!-- //.search-container -->
<!-- // 2nd Row  -->

<!-- 3rd Row Starts Here -->
<div class="search-container" align="center">
<div class="search" align="center">
    <form class="checkbox">
        <label>Day</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="monday" value="Monday">M
        <input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" value="Tuesday">T
        <input type="checkbox" name="wednesday" value="Wednesday">W
        <input type="checkbox" name="thursday" value="Thursday">R
        <input type="checkbox" name="friday" value="Friday">F
        <input type="checkbox" name="saturday" value="Saturday" >Sa
        <input type="checkbox" name="sunday" value="Tuesday">Su
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mid {background: #258db1; color: #fff; padding: 20px 0 30px 0;}
.mid h2 {color: #fff; text-align: center;}
.mid h2, .mid h3, .mid p, .footnote p {color:#fff;}

/* SEARCH */
#main-search-form {width: 100%;}
.search {min-width: 250px; display: inline; margin:0; position:relative;}
.search select {background: #fff; height: 40px; width: 150px; margin-bottom: 30px; margin-right: 30px; position:relative; display: inline;}
.search option, {padding: 10px; position:relative; display: inline;}
.search, .search label {display: inline;}
.search input#keywords {display: inline; position: relative; min-width: 250px; background: #fff; margin-right: 20px;}
.search .checkbox input {display: inline; position: relative; width: 15px!important; height: 15px!important; margin-left: 10px!important; margin-right: 2px!important;}
.search .checkbox label {display: inline; position: relative; margin-right: 10px;}

@media (max-width: 959px) {
    .search {disply: block; clear:both;}
    .search input, .search select, .search input#keywords {display:block; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 8px; width: 60%!important; margin-left:30px;}
    .search, .search label, .search input#keywords {display: block; clear:both;}
}
```

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

Remove align='center' attribute in #search